# Find area bounded by given curves. $y=\arcsin x,\;y=\arccos x,\,y=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Find area bounded by given curves.

$$y=\arcsin x,y=\arccos x,y=0 $$

[image]

So we need to find that shaded area.Intersection point is $\frac{\pi}{4}$

So we can write $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arcsin x + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{1} \arccos x$

and after calculation get $\frac{\pi}{4}(\arcsin(\frac{\pi}{4})-\arccos(\frac{\pi}{4}))$

but answer is $\sqrt2 - 1$

Comment: The intersection point is not $\pi/4$, is $(\sqrt{1/2},\pi/4)$.

Comment: Hint: By parts, $\displaystyle\int \arcsin x\,dx=x\arcsin x-\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ and the last integral is doable.

Comment: @jjagmath Yep instead of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ should be $\sqrt\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Instead of integrating horizontally, you should have gone for integrating vertically. Then it is one integral $ \int_0^{\pi/4} (\cos y - \sin y) ~ dy$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function when reflected in $y=x$ line goes to its own inverse. Since any point $(a, f(a))$ goes to $(f(a),a)$.

Reflecting your diagram about the $y=x$ line, the problem changes to

> Compute the area between the curves $y = \sin x$, $y = \cos x$ and $x=0$.

which should be a piece of cake.

> $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos x - \sin x \, dx  = \sqrt{2} - 1$$

Comment: I got the answer @MyMolecules but this way is interesting too and one question regarding thath. I can't think how prove when reflecting about $y=x$ will give same area?

Comment: @unit1991 On reflection, image has same size as object, hence area will be the same. You can try [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) for visualization; by plotting all four curves on same graph.

Comment: There is no reason for reflecting about $y = x$. As is, the integral can be written as $\int_0^{\pi/4} (\cos y - \sin y) ~ dy$

Comment: Oh well, I tried to be too fancy...